# Circle approximations using Bezier curves

Tags: math, graphics, bezier, java, renderer

I have 2 questions about bezier curves, and using them to approximate portions of circles.

1. Given the unit circle arc (1,0)->(cos(a),sin(a)) where 0 < a < pi/2, will it result
   in a good approximation of this arc to find the bezier curve's control points p1, p2 by solving the equations imposed by the requirements B(1/3) = (cos(a/3), sin(a/3))
   and B(2/3) = (cos(2a/3), sin(2a/3)). (In other words, requiring that the
   bezier curve go through two evenly spaced points in the arc).
2. If we have an affine transformation A which turns the circle arc in an
   ellipse arc will the transformed control points Ap0, Ap1, Ap2, Ap3 define
   a good bezier approximation to the ellipse arc?

p0 and p3, of course, are the start and end points of the curve: (1,0) and (cos(a), sin(a)).

Thank you

Comment: I would have done some error analysis myself, but I'm hoping someone knows off the top of their head.

Comment: Are your Bezier curves rational or without weights?

Comment: If this is for some manufacturing purpose, then maybe also consider approximating the ellipse with circular arcs, since CNC machines of all kinds support those directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a [general solution for any elliptical arc](https://modules.raku.org/dist/PDF::Document:cpan:TBROWDER/resources/elliptical-arc.pdf) as a cubic Bezier curve.

The error is most dependent on the difference of the start and end angles. I've had good success by limiting the angle difference to 60°. That is, I make a separate cubic segment for every 60° (or fraction thereof) and chain them together.

Comment: link is broken :-(

Answer (score 2):

Your questions basically ask "are these good approximations for a semicircle/arc of an ellipse".

You might want to try computing `B_y(a) - sin(a)` (of course, parameterizing your equations to both end at `(-1,0)` at the same value of `a`) for your curve `B(a)`, on a graphing utility such as [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) to graph it, and see how much the variance is, and whether or not it suits your purposes.

If you want a more precise and non-visual answer, you may calculate

```
Integral (from 0 to K) [B_y(a) - sin(a)]^2 da / 2
```

Where K is the value of `a` where both parameterized curves end up at `(-1,0)`.

This integral is related/proportional (somewhat) to some measure of Standard Deviation, and will serve well as a numerical analysis.  If it's within your desired accuracy, you are good.

Your second question, where you mention an affine transformation of a circle to an ellipse, will give you an error proportional to your original error, if your transformation is essentially linear.  If not, you could try using the [Jacobian Determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of your transformation to see how the error would vary.

I have also found a nice [**Analysis of Semicircle-Bezier Approximations**](http://digerati-illuminatus.blogspot.com/2008/05/approximating-semicircle-with-cubic.html) where the author finds a pretty sexy approximation:

[image: Bezier Semicircle]

Given by:

```
xValueInset = Diameter * 0.05
yValueOffset = radius * 4.0 / 3.0

P0 = (0,0)
P1 = (xValueInset, yValueOffset)
P2 = (Diameter - xValueInset, yValueOffset)
P3 = (Diameter, 0)
```

Where P1 and P2 are your control points.  Note that this approximates the semicircle:

```
B(a) = [ (d/2)*cos(a)+d/2 , (d/2)*sin(a) ]
```

Comment: as a follow up comment for people who found this post through google like I just did, this solution only looks good as semi-circle. It cannot be used for creating a full circle by sticking two of these together (the result is easily detected as "not a circle" by the human eye)

Comment: The fundamental error here is the non-continuity of the first derivative at the edges if you were to stick two together. The most common approximation is to use one bézier curve in each quadrant. I haven't seen anyone discuss a more accurate approximation, since that approach is "good enough."